# filter by multiple options in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a code below and I would like to show the filtered table based on all the criteria. How to get around with this, many thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data("mtcars"); head(mtcars,2)
mtcars <- rownames_to_column(mtcars, var="car") %>% head


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("mtcars"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mpg", "mpg Limit",
                  min = 11, max = 33, value = 20),
      
      sliderInput("cyl", "cyl Limit",
                  min = 4, max = 8, value = 2)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("mtcars_kable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$mtcars_kable <- function() {
    req(input$mpg & input$cyl)
    mtcars %>%
      #dplyr::mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>% 
      dplyr::select(car, everything()) %>%
      dplyr::filter(mpg <= input$mpg & cyl = input$cyl) %>%
      knitr::kable("html") %>%
      kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
      add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
  }
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your `cyl = input$cyl` should be `cyl == input$cyl`?

Comment: With @akrun's correction above, your code appears to run correctly.  What is the issue?